# .Net chart control XY graph bad output when all X values are the same

Tags: c#, mschart

I'm using the chart control to display a scatter graph.

In some cases the data series consists of points with equal X values.

In these cases all I see is a single point (instead of a vertical line).
In addition, the location of the point is not based on the actual coordinates.
Altering the X value of a point solves this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting two y-values for x=0 in a MS Chart control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786931/plotting-two-y-values-for-x-0-in-a-ms-chart-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this entry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/MSWinWebChart/thread/ab6fd210-dc1e-44b2-a1f7-dffd3cbf821e), there isn't much you can do.

Check weather you run in a case that would cause the problem and add something tiny to one of your points (double.Epsilon).

I once used something like this to go over my plots after a single point was set (slightly different problem, but you get the idea ...):

```
foreach (var l_oSeries in Series)
{
    if (l_oSeries.Points.Count != 1)
        continue;

    if (l_oSeries.Points[0].XValue == 0)
    {
        l_oSeries.Points[0].XValue = double.Epsilon;
    }
}
```

Not elegant, but does the job.