# Plotting two y-values for x=0 in a MS Chart control

Tags: c#, mschart

I found a weird behavior in MS Chart for Windows Forms.

Let's say I want to have a scatter plot with two points (1,10) and (1,20). I can do that in this way:

```
....
Series series = new Series();
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
double[] x = { 1, 1 };
double[] y = { 10, 20 };
series.Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
```

That works fine. But now I want the same result, but both x-values should be `0`.

```
double[] x = { 0, 0 };
double[] y = { 10, 20 };
series.Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
```

In that case the chart control creates two data points at 'autogenerated' x positions 1 and 2. It just ignores the given x-values. It is the same behavior if I use

```
series.Points.AddXY(0, 10);
series.Points.AddXY(0, 20);
```

I get the same effect for more than two data points. So it turns out that scatter plot does not work if not at least one x-value is nonzero.

I think a possible workaround would be to use multiple series, but that is inacceptable.

Does anyone have a explanation for this behavior or a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution by myself:

You have to add

```
series.CustomProperties = "IsXAxisQuantitative=True";
```

to your code. So the x-values really are treated as values. I don't know why this is not self-evident if I use the BindXY function.

Comment: `series["IsXAxisQuantitative"] = "true";` is equivalent but will avoid overwriting any existing custom properties.

Answer (score 0):

(I would just comment on Fratyx's answer, but I guess don't have the reputation to do so.)

To elaborate on Fratyx's answer, the `IsXAxisQuantitative` property only applies to certain `SeriesChartType`'s, and will be ignored for other types.

These are those types:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/Common/Utilities/CustomAttributesRegistry.cs,e51a969ce4c7db16